# he knows what a big responsibility it would be / he knew what a big responsibility it would be

Tags: imaginary-situations

> He never had pets because **he knows what a big responsibility it would be**.

If I understand correctly, "it would be" is strongly connected with "he knows". Or "it would be" can be independent here? So, if "it would be" is strongly connected with "he knows", we can't say:

> He never had pets because **he knew what a big responsibility it would be**.

But we can say:

> He never had pets because **he knew what a big responsibility it would have been**.

**Addition:**

*Some people says the second version is the best one but I know "would" isn't used with permanent states in the past. In my example it is "he knew". Am I right?*

Comment: I think the second version is better. "He never had pets (when he was young, presumably) because he knew (at the time) what a big responsibility it would be." Saying that he knows it _now_ doesn't necessarily indicate that he knew it _then_.

Comment: @Kate Bunting, Do you think the second version is better than the third one? I have information we need to use "it would have been" if we speak about a situation in the past.

Comment: I think the first sentence would work if you shifted it to the present tense: *He doesn't have pets because he knows what a bit responsibility it is/would be.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first version doesn’t work at all, but the second and third versions both work, more or less. The second version is more commonly seen because it conveys the same information as the third in a more concise manner.

> He **knew** what a big responsibility it would be

Here, “knew” refers to his mindset at the time. That is, he knew back then that it **would be** a big responsibility in the future.

In my opinion, the use of “would have been” in the third version implies that in the past, he considered it a big responsibility, and in the present, he no longer does.